# Check for system requirements failed

Tags: cytoscape

I tried to install Cytoscape on Win10 64bit. After I ran the windows.bat file, I get the following lines in the message:

find: 'TTL=': No such file or directory

Problem: The "app" store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable with a timeout of 30000ms

Summary

Your system has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again:
- App store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable

There is no problem for me to access the website of apps.cytoscape.org using a browser. So what is the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that running the windows.bat file as an Administrator solved the "find: 'TTL=': No such file or directory" problem